# Objective C Full Name to Logon Name

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a user's full name (like the one returned by `NSFullUserName()`). Is there any way in c or objective c to confert this to a logon name (like the one returned by `NSUserName()`).

However, I cannot use `NSFullUserName()` because the full name I have is not necessarily the name of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login name (`NSUserName`) and the full/display name (`NSFullUserName`) have no automated relationship. A user, when creating an account or at any time afterward in System Preferences, can choose whatever they like for both names — so there's no way to generate one given the other and be guaranteed it's correct.

Comment: OS X knows both names and will log you in using either. You can get more info about the logged in user (and other user records that the current user has privileges to see) with [Open Directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/Open_Directory/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000917) APIs, but that still won't necessarily let you directly look up one user name given a possible other.